# Launch ListActivity from an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter, listactivity

I am trying to use a menu bar intent activity to launch an activity but the app always crashes. It was hoped to launch a ListActivity activity to perform some tasks. Although the ListActivity works fine when used on its own (i.e. as the usual MainActivity from app launch), there is a problem to alternatively use it in Activity2.class via an intent when user clicks the menu bar option for this. The other menu bar items, however, would work okay when clicked.

Exert from MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// class code goes here ....

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

    // other options too in switch statement

    case R.id.activity2:
        MyActivity();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

//code to launch activity
public void MyActivity()
{
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(.MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
}

}
```

Turning to the AndroidManifest.xml file exert,

```
//launch ListActivity in Activity2.class when user clicks the Menu Bar option
<activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity2" >

</activity>
}
```

Now an exert from Activity2.class:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;

public class Activity2 extends ListActivity {

// code goes here

}
```

An exert from the main.xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/activity2"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_act"/>
</menu>
```

And exert activity_main.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity2"
>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/mylist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lists"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Using an optional intent filter,

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity2"
    android:label="@string/title_activity2" >
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This doesn't improve anything.

The Activity2.class calls an onStart() method, amongst others. This all worked when the file was used as a MainActivity prior to changing to Activity2:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
super.onStart();

}
```

Comment: Does it even compile? This `.MainActivity.this` doesn't look right.

Comment: In the end, it was a problem with using ProGuard correctly, not the code above!